# Query two different types of post in one page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have two different post types one is books and the other is supports. I am trying to call this two post in one page.

How can I do that? Here is the code I am using to query a post:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=books&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1&paged='.
get_query_var('paged')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) should never be used. Rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
           'post_type'=>array('books','supports'),
           'post_status'=>'publish',
           'posts_per_page'=>-1,
           'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'=>array('books','supports'),
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: when i am inserting it in dreamweaver it shows an php error. can u give me the full code. thanks

Comment: @user3396867 Oops, i forgot to put quotes around the post type strings. I have edited my answer to correct, it should work fine now

Comment: sorry but again en error! this is the full code i have inserted      <?php 
 query_posts(
    'post_type'=>array('books','supports'),
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
 ?>

Comment: Never use `query_posts`